# Access Android's date picker using Jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, datepicker

I'm working on an application for IOS/Android using phonegap[cordova 2.2.0]

I use jquery/Html5.

For IOS, I just choose input type to be "date" or "time" then the datepicker/[timepicker is displayed when I click on the input.

```
   <input type="time" name="basic" value=""  />
   <input type="date" name="reminder" value=""  />
```

But this isn't working with Andriod, so is there any other method in which I can display the date picker using Html5/Javascript/Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have two ways to do it:
1. [Android Datepicker Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker)
2.[Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/)

Mobiscroll works both on Android and iOS, but it is slow.
Native plugin on Android is quite good, but not so flexible.

Comment: They work for me. What have you tried? Android datepicker plugin definetely works.